# Conditionally join some of an array's items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have two arrays of same length:

```
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const b = [1, 1, 2, 1];
```

I want to join (`.join('')`) all consecutive items in `a` whose corresponding value in `b` (i.e. at the same index) are equal.

In this scenario, what I want to get is:

```
const result = ['ab', 'c', 'd']
```

Because `a[0]` and `a[1]` have the same corresponding value in `b` (i.e. `b[0] === b[1]`) and are consecutive in `a`, they are joined into the same string, forming a single item in `result`. However, although `a[3]`'s corresponding value in `b` is equal to `a[0]` and `a[1]`'s one, it's not joined to any of the latter as it isn't consecutive.

Comment: Nice, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the value at `b` is the same at the given index and the sucessor.

```js
const
    a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    b = [1, 1, 2, 1],
    result = a.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        if (b[i - 1] === b[i]) r[r.length - 1] += v;
        else r.push(v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two seporate loops; one to combine the two arrays in an object and merge consecutive objects with the same id, and one to grab the other value from the first loop and create a new array.

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const b = [1, 1, 2, 1];

var step = [];
for (n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
  if(step[n-1] !== undefined && step[n-1].id === b[n]) {
    step[step.length-1].text = step[step.length-1].text + a[n];
  } else {
    step.push({ id: b[n], text: a[n] });
  }
}
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < step.length; i++) {
  result.push(step[i].text);
}

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
//console.log(step); //for testing
console.log(result);
```